# How to avoid typescript transform unicode chars to ascii?

Tags: typescript

For example:

```
const program = ts.createSourceFile('temp.ts', 'console.log("")', ts.ScriptTarget.ESNext);
console.log(ts.createPrinter().printFile(program));
```

Its output like this:

```
console.log("\uD83D\uDE02");
```

I hope it print the original unicode source like this:

```
console.log("")
```

Comment: Well, I found the solution after read the source code. You can use `ts.setEmitFlags(program, ts.EmitFlag.NoAsciiEscaping)` to avoid escape non-ascii characters. But, the `ts.Printer` could not handle `TSX` node correctly, which will be fixed in `TypeScript 3.4`, please avoid use this API in your project, `recast` is a good alternate.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not directly related to TypeScript compiler. Indeed, looking in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=console.log(%22%F0%9F%98%82%22)%3B%0D%0A), `console.log("");` is transpiled with no modification.

Where does `ts` come from? Is it some `gulp` script? It's probably where to look.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the [TypeScript Compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API)

Comment: This API is labelled "not yet stable". Still you can open an issue on this github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Hitting same issue. Our workaround:

```
    let content = printer.printFile(file);
    content = unescape(content.replace(/\\u/g, "%u"));
```